# Expectation of product of random variables

Tags: probability, expected-value

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, is the following statement true: $E(XYX)=E(X)E(Y)E(X)$? I am somewhat confused about this expectation of the product. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No. If $Y=1$ then $X$ and $Y$ are independent for any $X$. Your equation becomes $EX^{2}=(EX)^{2}$ which is true only whne $X$ is a.s. constant.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Thanks, Kavi. That helps!